# Opening a PHP link in a jQuery UI dialog

Tags: php, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#register").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        show: {
            effect:"",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect:"",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $("#register-opener").click(function() {
        $("#register").dialog("open");
    });
});

<td><a id="register-opener" href="?id=<? echo "$members_row[id]"; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit"></i></a></td>
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish is to click on a link to be able to edit a certain users information, the problem is I can only get the popup to occur when replacing the href with href="#". Can someone assist. Thanks.

Comment: So I have gotten a couple of different solutions to work, but only if there is one user in the db, it automatically stops working when multiple users appear in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in jQuery to achieve this.

```
$("#register-opener").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#register").dialog("open");
});
```

Above script will make sure that when ever user clicks on link it doesn't go to URL mentioned in `href` and execute following codes.

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

> If **e.preventDefault()** is called then default action of the
>   **event**(click in above case) will not be triggered.

Comment: ok so that still actually doesn't work. Would it matter where the elements are on the page compared to one another?

Comment: No, that's doesn't matter.  How does your jQuery function look like?

Comment: `$(function() {
  $("#register").dialog({
   autoOpen:false,
   show: {
    effect:"",
    duration: 1000
   },
   hide: {
    effect:"",
    duration: 1000
   }
  });
  
  $("#register-opener").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#register").dialog("open");
  });
 });`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be problem with dialogue function you have. Use prompt instead and be sure to remove icon inside `a` tag

```js
    jQuery("#register-opener").click(function() {
      var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("#yourid").innerHTML =
    "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  //Or do your thing
}
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a id="register-opener" href="?id=<?php echo '$members_row[id]'; ?>">
    icon<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit">
    </i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be better accomplished by putting your ID in a `data-` attribute rather than using `href`, which is meant to be used for specifying a URL for the web browser to follow.

```
<td><a id="register-opener" href="#" data-id="<? echo $members_row[id]; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit"></i></a></td>
```

You can then access the value of the `data-id` attribute in jQuery by using

```
$("register-opener").attr("data-id");
```